# parallelism in spark sql when list of tables are need to be processed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 1.6.0 , cdh 5.7.0

I have a csv file which has list of tables to be processed and I want to achieve parallelism in processing. 
As of now I am using collect to process each , tried using future option in scala and even tried this https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/10/21/demystifying-asynchronous-actions-in-spark/

```
 val allTables = sc.textFile("hdfs://.......")
    allTables.collect().foreach(
    table => {
    val processing = sqlContext.sql(s"select * from ${table} ")
    processing.saveAsParquetFile("hdfs://.......")
             } 
                               )
```

Comment: It looks from the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) (that's the latest version, but I don't think it has changed) that the trick is to use the FAIR scheduler as described in the docs and your link and to submit the processing jobs for different threads.

Comment: To be clear, I haven't done this, I just recalled having read something about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use scala collection parallel feature as well.

```
allTables.collect().par.foreach(table => ..)
```